# Changing speed of an object falling down

Tags: android

I am creating an Android game and I have been encountering problems when increasing the score.

So there are 2 objects, one placed in the middle of the screen and one object falling down to the bottom of the screen.

When the object falling down passes the object in the middle of the screen it adds a point.

When I set the speed of the falling object to **skullY += 5** or **skullY += 10** everything works fine and the point is added to the score, but if I change the speed to something like **skullY += 7** or **skullY += 12** it will go faster and would not add the score when it passes.

This is the problem I am currently encountering.

This is my Activity code:

```
 //BOX AND SKULL X AND Y
private float boxX, boxY;
private float skullX, skullY;
private float skullX1, skullY1;

//BOX SKULL PICTURES
private ImageView box;
private ImageView skull, skull1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_state);
    decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

    frame = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);

    txtTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimer);
    txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScore);

    box = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.box);
    skull = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.skull);
    skull1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.skull1);

    startCountDownTimer();
}

public void startTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    initializeTimerTask();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 100, 20);
}

public void stoptimertask() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}

public void initializeTimerTask() {
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    goDownBoxAndSkull();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}


//FUNCTIONS FOR BOX AND SKULL TO GO DOWN
public void goDownBoxAndSkull() {

    //SKULL FUNCTIONS
    //SCORE CHECK TO SET NEW SPEED
    if (scoreCount >= 0 && scoreCount < 5) {

        skullY += 5;

        if (skullY > frame.getHeight()) {
            newXposition = (int) box.getX();

            skullY = -150.0f;
            skullX = newXposition;
        }
        if (skullX < 0) {
            skullX = 0;
        }
        skull.setX(skullX);
        skull.setY(skullY);
    }

    if (scoreCount >= 5 && scoreCount < 1000) {
        skull1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        skullY += 10;
        skullY1 += 10;

        if (skullY > frame.getHeight()) {
            newXposition = (int) box.getX();

            skullY = -150.0f;
            skullX = newXposition;
        }
        if (skullX < 0) {
            skullX = 0;
        }

        if (skullY1 > frame.getHeight()) {
            newXposition = (int) box.getX();

            skullY1 = -150.0f;
            skullX1 = newXposition;
        }
        if (skullX1 < 0) {
            skullX1 = 0;
        }
        skull.setX(skullX);
        skull.setY(skullY);

        skull1.setX(skullX1);
        skull1.setY(skullY1);
    }

    //CHECK IF BOX PASSED SKULL TO ADD SCORE
    if (skull.getY() == box.getY()) {
        scoreCount++;
        txtScore.setText("SCORE: " + String.valueOf(scoreCount));
    }
    if (skull1.getY() == box.getY()) {
        scoreCount++;
        txtScore.setText("SCORE: " + String.valueOf(scoreCount));
    }



    //BOX FUNCTIONS
    if (tapped == true) {
        boxX -= 5;
    } else {
        boxX += 5;
    }

    //BOX GOING TO LEFT
    if (boxX < 0) {
        boxX = 0;
    }

    //BOX GOING TO RIGHT
    if (boxX > frame.getWidth() - box.getWidth())
    {
        boxX = frame.getWidth() - box.getWidth();
    }
    box.setX(boxX);
}

 //COUNTDOWN TIMER TO START
public void startCountDownTimer()
{
    new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtTimer.setText("GAME WILL START IN \n" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            startTimer();

            txtScore.setText("SCORE: " + String.valueOf(scoreCount));
            txtTimer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtScore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            box.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            skull.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //SET RANDOM START POSITION FOR SKULL
            newXposition = r.nextInt(frame.getWidth());
            skullX = newXposition;
            skull.setX(skullX);

            //SET BOX IN THE MIDDLE
            boxX = frame.getWidth() / 2;
            boxY = frame.getHeight() / 2;
            box.setX(boxX);
            box.setY(boxY);
         }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Just friendly advice: use a SurfaceView instead. This kind of action on Views are harder than just rendering to a Canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is wide but if I understood you add a score here:

```
if (skull.getY() == box.getY()) {
        scoreCount++;
        txtScore.setText("SCORE: " + String.valueOf(scoreCount));
    }
    if (skull1.getY() == box.getY()) {
        scoreCount++;
        txtScore.setText("SCORE: " + String.valueOf(scoreCount));
    }
```

In the first case you use increment so that each one is multiple of the box position, so the `==` condition is satisfied.

In the second case, they are not multiples, and this can cause the condition to be never met.

Just do something like this to solve:

```
if (skull.getY() >= box.getY() && skull.scoreCounted == false) {
        skull.scoreCounted = true;
        scoreCount++;
        txtScore.setText("SCORE: " + String.valueOf(scoreCount));
    }
    if (skull1.getY() >= box.getY() && skull1.scoreCounted == false) {
        skull.scoreCounted = true;
        scoreCount++;
        txtScore.setText("SCORE: " + String.valueOf(scoreCount));
    }
```

**EDIT**: Suppose you have a `skull.scoreCounted` public boolean flag, you can use it to know if the point for that box was already considered or not.

The code is a bit unclear and I can't manage to say wether the comparison should be `>=` or `=<`.

By the way, I wouldn't suggest creating games this way since it's inefficient and uncomfortable and quite bad I think.

If you're interested in Android Game Development check out some ad hoc framework like [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com)

Comment: Actually sir the reason why I made it `==` condition. Is that when I use `skull.getY() >= box.getY()` the score will continue to increment if the skull y-axis is greater than the box y-axis and vice versa with the `<` condition. Because I have a timer that acts as the update for the box to fall down every 20 milliseconds.

Comment: Oh, you are right. You should then add a margin or work with speeds that will ensure you that the `==` is satisfied... Or maybe use some flag to add the point once per box. The problem lies there.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a possible, dirty workaround

Comment: Yes ma'am/sir. I will take your advice that I should start focusing on libgdx. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad for it! If you're interested, let me suggest you start here: https://www.udacity.com/course/2d-game-development-with-libgdx--ud405 it's a free course on Udacity which taught me the basics for libgdx and I found it quite useful to start. (btw it's sir, I'm a boy lol)

Comment: Okay sir haha. I will accept your answer, since you pointed me to a better direction. And it said it easy to port the app to android and ios which is also good. haha. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you can export to Android, iOS, desktop (multiplatform, it's java!) and html5!